# Toa Terrain Crawler alternate build instructions

Tags: instructions, bionicle, alternate-model

I was building the LEGO Bionicle Toa Terrain Crawler, (8927), when I saw at the back of the instructions a photo of an alternate helicopter-type build. Where can I find the instructions on how to build this model?[image]

Comment: A [search](https://www.backoftheboxbuilds.com/?s=8927) at the usual resource for instructions of these [back of the box builds](https://www.backoftheboxbuilds.com) does not give any results.

Comment: That's an "idea" or "inspirational" model which were present for some models back in the day. These type of models never had instructions (or full instructions) from LEGO. The only hope someone within community build this model digitally and share the file or PDF instructions.

Answer (score -1):

You can find them in The LEGO Customer Service site. Search for the set you'd like to rebuild, and you can download the instructions. Some Technic sets include a few parts or stickers that you won't need while building the main model. [https://www.lego.com/en-my/service/help/bricks-and-sets/building-instructions/additional-instructions-blt2c8ffc2c6ffa17b8#:~:text=You%20can%20find%20them%20right,while%20building%20the%20main%20model](https://www.lego.com/en-my/service/help/bricks-and-sets/building-instructions/additional-instructions-blt2c8ffc2c6ffa17b8#:%7E:text=You%20can%20find%20them%20right,while%20building%20the%20main%20model).

Comment: There would already been an answer if it was THIS easy.